# How can I show the git branch of a rails app within that app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I've got a couple of different branches of a rails app running in a development environment on the same server (on separate databases, obv), and I'd like to make it very clear what branch is being shown when I hit the app through the web.

Any ideas, short of running `git-branch` or `git-symbolic-ref HEAD` in backticks and parsing the output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [Grit](http://github.com/schacon/grit/tree/master), it allows you to read a Git repository using Ruby.

```
repository = Grit::Repo.new(RAILS_ROOT)
repository.head.name # => "master"
```

Comment: Grit hasn't been updated for years, perhaps this is a viable alternative: https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as you suggested, shelling out is the right thing to do.

If you're afraid somehow `git` might not be available to the app, you might try reading the file `.git/HEAD`.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, this can be achieved using the gem `git`: https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git

```rb
require 'git'
g = Git.open(Rails.root)
g.describe('HEAD', tags: true)
```